# How to lapply to this function?

Tags: r

This is the function declaration (`fOptions::GBSGreeks`) I want to apply a list to:

```
function (Selection = c("Delta", "Theta", "Vega", "Rho", "Lambda", 
    "Gamma", "CofC"), TypeFlag = c("c", "p"), S, X, Time, r, 
     b, sigma)
```

I want to try various `Selection` while fixing all other parameters. I tried:

```
library(fOptions)

greeks <- lapply(Selection=list('Delta', 'Gamma', 'Vega', 'Theta', 'Rho'),
             FUN=fOptions::GBSGreeks, TypeFlag='p', S=100.0, X=100.0, Time=1.0, r=0.05, b=0, sigma=0.05)
```

but the result is just a single element:

```
[[1]]
[1] -0.4661285
```

**Q**: How to do lapply in my example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
greeks <- lapply(list('Delta', 'Gamma', 'Vega', 'Theta', 'Rho'),
             function(a) GBSGreeks(Selection = a,
                                   TypeFlag='p', 
                                   S=100.0, X=100.0, 
                                   Time=1.0, r=0.05, b=0, sigma=0.05))
```